# Creating a child object from parent in PHP7

Tags: php

Let's say I have a parent class `X` and a child class `Y extends X`. Now I have an Object of `X` which holds public and private attributes.

Now, I want to create an object of `Y` which has the exact same values as my previously created `X`.

```
NOT WORKING EXAMPLE

class X { public $var; }

class Y extends X {}

$x = new X();
$x->var = 5;

$y = new Y(); // This object should have the same properties as X    
echo $y->var; // Should echo 5
```

**EDIT**

I know this is not a pretty standard way PHP should behave, but I need this functionality to convert some legacy php code to work with a new set of child classes.

Comment: What? Why should it echo `5`? They're different instances. You're expecting static behaviour on non-static variables? Are you looking for `clone`? Or perhaps you're hoping to be able to do some sort of object conversion?

Comment: That's **NOT** how objects work. Every instance of an object is (ignoring static members) completely independent of every OTHER instance of an object. setting something in `X` doesn't magically make that something appear in all further/newer instances of that class. In other words, if you put something into your car's glove box, doesn't mean that all other copies of the car get that something as well.

Comment: And also you title suggest that it doesnt work on php7 but works on php5 which is not true because it will also not work on php5 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way I can think of right now to do that automatically.

However, you could include a constructor in your `Y` class to accept an `X` instance as parameter:

```
class Y extends X {
  public function __construct(X $x) {
    $this->var = $x->var;
    // if you want to keep the two bound to each other, you could do
    // $this->var =& $x->var;
  }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
$x = new X();
$x->var = 5;

$y = new Y($x); // pass original X instance
echo $y->var; // now is 5
```

There is also the possibility to [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) an object, but that cannot change its class.

Comment: Yes I see. Well in my real world example my Object `X` holds a lot of variables, and It will be a pain to implement this. Thank you for the example anyways.

Comment: There is also the possibility to clone an object, but that cannot change its class.